# Formal language without grammar

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

Definitions:

- *Alphabet* $Σ$: finite, non-empty set
- *Language*: subset of $Σ^*$
- *Grammar*: [Unrestricted grammar (Chomsky Type 0)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrestricted_grammar)
- *Language of a grammar*: all words that can be produced by applying $P$ multiple times, starting from $S$

Grammars are finite, therefore there are only countable infinite of them. But there are uncountably infinite many languages. Each grammar can only describe one language. Therefore, there are **languages without grammars**.

Can you give an **example** for such a language without grammar?

I searched the internet, but strangely, I could not even find the question in context of formal language.

Comment: Whenever you have a question about grammars, the [Dragon book](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) is a good place to look.

Comment: The same statement can be made about Turing machines: there are countably infinte TMs, but uncountably many languages. This is often used as the "intuition" for the existence of undecidable languages.

Comment: @jmite Intuition? That's a full-blown proof right there!

Comment: I guess "intuition" isn't the right word. Explanation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that by "grammar" you mean type-0 grammars. One can probably extend those to capture more languages.

Type-0 grammars are equivalent to Turing machines in expressive power. So, in order to show that a given language does not have a grammar, we can proceed as follows with suitable $L$:

> Assume there was a grammar for $L$. Then, we could semi-decide the word problem of $L$. That contradicts the known fact that $L$ is not recursively-enumerable.

Note the *semi* here; assuming a grammar does not give us decidability, so the halting problem is not a suitable candidate -- we need a problem/language that is not even semi-decidable/recursively enumerable. From your computability background you should know that the *complement* of the (special) halting language, namely

$\qquad \overline{H} = \{ \langle M \rangle \mid M \text{ loops on } \langle M \rangle \}$,

is not semi-decidable. Thus, by the reduction outlined above, there is no (Chomsky) grammar for $\overline{H}$.

Answer (score 3):

While the halting problem is a perfectly valid example of a language that a CFG can not capture, there is a huge middle ground of languages that are not context free but recursive (that is they can be solved by a Turing machine but can not be expressed by a CFG).

For example, you can use the [pumping lemma for CFGs](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages) to show that the language $ L = \{ a^i b^i c^i| i \in \mathbb N \} $ is not context free.

Comment: The question does not talk about context-free languages.

Comment: @Raphael: but the definition of grammar given by the OP corresponds to Type-2 grammars

Comment: @Vor Huh, true enough. Curious.

Comment: This is the answer to the question I asked, but not the one I was interested in. Sorry for the confusion. :-/

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found an example: The non-halting programs. No Turing machine can determine that a program will not halt.

This is also why the type-0 languages are not closed under complementation.

Comment: That's wrong; there are plenty of grammars for non-halting programs.

Comment: How is the *language of non-halting programs* different from the *complement of the halting language*, which is what you provided as an example in your question?

Comment: The complement of the halting language requires to check for non-termination *at a specific position*. The set of non-total programs is different in that regard; it can be recursively enumerated (proving this is a popular exercise in compatibility classes). Hint: For enumeration, it is sufficient to enforce non-termination in at least one position in a smart way -- no need to *check*. (I guess a full answer would be worth its own question here.)